# Remove quot on hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have action for search locations of province like this :

```
def search_locations
    @locations = Location.where(:province_id => params[:province_id])

    @location_options = []
    @locations.each do |l|
      hash = {}
      hash[:id] = l.id
      hash[:text] = l.name.to_s
      @location_options.push(hash)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

I want to write hash on file `search_locations.js.erb`

```
var data = <%= @location_options.to_json %>;
```

But object has quotes on output :

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:0,text:&quot;a&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:1,text:&quot;b&quot;}]
```

I want to the output like this :

```
[{id:0,text:"a"},{id:1,text:"b"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = <%= raw(@location_options.to_json) %>;
```

Or:

```
var data = <%= @location_options.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

Comment: I have tried that before ask but object still has double quotes `[{"id":0,"text":"a"},{"id":1,"text":"b"}]`

Comment: @itx you want change double quotes to single quotes?

Comment: no, I want to the output like this `[{id:0,text:"a"},{id:1,text:"b"}]`

Comment: can you tell why? for `javascript` no difference what kind of quotes in object:`var s = {foo: 1}; s.foo => 1; s["foo"] => 1; var s = {'foo': 1};  s.foo => 1`